Why does chrome extension warn "read your browsing history"?
I have no permissions listed that should give this warning, however, it appears when trying to install the extension.
screenshot
{
 "manifest_version": 3,
 "name": "app name",
 "description": "",
 "version": "0.0.3",
 "icons": {
   "16": "icons/16.png",
   "32": "icons/32.png",
   "48": "icons/48.png",
   "128": "icons/128.png"
 },
 "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "scripting",
   "storage", 
   "windows",
   "https://localhost:4200/*",
   "https://character.ai/*",
   "https://www.figgs.ai/*", 
   "https://static.figgs.ai/*",
   "https://janitorai.com/*",
   "https://ella.janitorai.com/*",
   "https://spicychat.ai/*",
   "https://ndsc.b-cdn.net/*"
 ],
 "host_permissions": [
   "http://localhost:4200/*",
   "https://character.ai/*",
   "https://www.figgs.ai/*",
   "https://static.figgs.ai/*", 
   "https://janitorai.com/*",
   "https://ella.janitorai.com/*",
   "https://spicychat.ai/*",
   "https://ndsc.b-cdn.net/*"
 ],
 "web_accessible_resources": [
   {
     "resources": [
       "app.tsx",
       "main.js"
     ],
     "matches": [
       "<all_urls>"
     ]
   }
 ],
 "background": {
   "service_worker": "background.js"
 },
 "action": {
   "default_title": "Exporter",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": [
       "http://localhost:4200/*",
     ],
     "js": [
       "content-scripts/content.js"
     ]
   }
 ]
}

According to the google permissions documentation, the only permission strings that should give the "read your browsing history" warning are the "declarativeNetRequestFeedback", "sessions", "tabs", and "webNavigation" strings. My manifest.json does not list any of these so I am confused if there is something else in my manifest.json that could trigger this. Any solutions?

I don't see a "windows" permission in the docs. What is that? It sounds vaguely like it could be related to, or perhaps a deprecated version of, the "tabs" permission, and the "tabs" permission gives a "Read your browsing history." warning.

@user2357112 you may be correct. "chrome.windows" is related to "tabs". I missed this when reviewing the documentation:
"Gives access to privileged fields of the Tab objects used by several APIs, including chrome.tabs and chrome.windows. You usually don't need to declare this permission to use those APIs.
Warning displayed: Read your browsing history."

If you know your manifest file has LLM hallucinations in it, your first step should be to write a manifest file that you actually think is valid.

It's probably a bug in the browser UI caused by your previous attempts. Remove the extension and install it again or use getPermissionWarningsByManifest (example) or Extension Update Testing Tool.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
